# Fetching table's data row by row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How can I fetch data from a table in ms-access row by row using sql and vba then showing every value in msgbox.
How can I use for loop statement to achieve that.

Comment: Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.gotorecord

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/move-through-a-dao-recordset